# populate multiple select dropdownlist using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im trying to populate my multiple dropdown list using ajax. but its not working. this dropdown list is dependent on another dropdown list which is single selection dropdown list.
Html Code is :

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="InputGender">Select Course</label>
        <div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="sub_id"  id="sub_id">
            <option value="">Select Course Name</option>
            <?php
              while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
             ?> 
            <option value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
        </select>
         <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span> 
       </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
   <label>Second Level Category</label><br />
   <select id="chap_id" name="chap_id[]" multiple class="form-control">

   </select>
   </div>
```

Ajax Code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#sub_id").change(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'AddQuestionAjax.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {subId:id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response){

                var len = response.length;

                $("#chap_id").empty();
         $("#chap_id").append("<option value=''>Select Chapter</option>");

                for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                    var cid = response[i]['id'];
                    var cname = response[i]['name'];
                    $("#chap_id").append("<option value='"+cid+"'>"+cname+"</option>");

                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

below is JSON response or the code writted in AddQuestionAjax.php file

```
 <?php
session_start();
require 'conn.php';

$tSubId = $_POST['subId'];   // department id
$sql = "SELECT * FROM chapter WHERE Subject_subId=".$tSubId;

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$sub_arr = array();

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
$sid = $row['idChapter'];
$sname = $row['chapName'];

$sub_arr[] = array("id" => $sid, "name" => $sname);
}

// encoding array to json format*/
echo json_encode($sub_arr);
?>
```

Comment: what exactly issue is? Not working whole part or ajax?

Comment: I am guessing the issue is mainly the complete absence of any code to fill the second dropdown, right? Please add the `AddQuestionAjax.php` code to your question

Comment: pl add AddQuestionAjax code

Comment: Who upvotes questions like this? Please read the tooltip that shows when you hover over the upvote arrow!

Comment: And how is `cakephp` relevant to this question

Comment: code is working http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/w3z6-cfbb

Comment: there is nothing wrong with AddQuestionAjax.php file. It's returning the result back to the function. problem is only where I'm trying to append the result for multiple dropdown list in AJAX function. this result is not binding with multiple dropdwon list.

Comment: Can you share your JSON response?

Comment: first I'm selecting the value from #sub_id dropdown list and want have that selected value result in my second multiple dropdown list. Also I'm getting the result back "AddQuestionAjax.php" and binding this result with the Second list but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about PHP section code but i've tried this. Just a example what you are doing here and it is working perfectly

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputGender">Select Course</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="sub_id" id="sub_id">
            <option value="">Select Course Name</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Second Level Category</label>
    <br />
    <select id="chap_id" name="chap_id[]" multiple class="form-control">

    </select>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#sub_id").change(function() {
            var response = [{
                id: 1,
                name: 'a'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                name: 'b'
            }];
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                var cid = response[i]['id'];
                var cname = response[i]['name'];
                $("#chap_id").append("<option value='" + cid + "'>" + cname + "</option>");

            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

you also need to parse the JSON before looping thorough your records. Which can be done by this

```
var res = JSON.parse(response);
```

Then parhaps you can add your records in select picker